# How to convert an SQL Output to a python list

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, tkinter

So basically I have an SQL database with 5 different columns of data.
what I am trying to do is take the data from my SQL query and put it into a list so I can display it in tkinter's treeview widget.

**Questions:**

1. Is there an easier way to take data from an SQL table and display it in a table-like format in tkinter? If so how?
2. Is it a good idea to make a table in tkinter with the treeview widget?
3. If not, what widget should I use?

I have tried to convert my SQL output to a list but it keeps giving errors similar to:

```
list index out of range
```

Here is my complete code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

#lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'avo', 'rasberry']

con = sqlite3.connect("user_info.db")
cur = con.cursor()
root = Tk()

tv = ttk.Treeview(root)
tv.pack()
tv.config(columns= ("name", 'age', 'email', 'town'))

tv.heading('#0', text='ID')
tv.column('#0', width = 100)

tv.heading('1', text = "Age")
tv.column('1', width = 100)

tv.heading('name', text = 'Name')
tv.column('name', width = 100)

tv.heading('2', text = "email")
tv.column("2", width = 100)

tv.heading('3', text = "Town")
tv.column("3", width = 100)

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user')
fr = cur.fetchall()

print(fr)c
print(cur)
tv.insert("",'0', 'item1', text = fr[0])
tv.set('item1', 'name', fr[1])
tv.set('item1', 'age', fr[2])
tv.set('item1', 'email', fr[3])
tv.set('item1', 'town', fr[4])
root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for the weird layout

Comment: show us your python code

Comment: always put code, error mesage and data in question - it will be more readable.

Comment: ill do that now

Comment: i added the full code (not too big)\

Comment: BTW: tkinter doesn't have standard widgets for tables. See [pandastable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) or [tkintertable](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/tkintertable) - they can be easier then `Treeview`

Comment: you should rather use `for row in cur.fetchall(): print(row[0])`, not `fr[0]`. `fr[0]` should give you first row, not first element in row. Simply use `print()` to see what you have in `fr[0]`

Comment: i tried that and i got this. "name 'row' is not defined"

Comment: did you use correct indentation ? `print(row[0]) has to be inside `for`-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is minimal example which create database with two elements and later it uses data from database to fill Treeview

You have to use `create()` only once.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

def create(con):
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  user (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        age TEXT NOT NULL,
        email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        town TEXT NOT NULL
    );''')

    cur.execute('INSERT INTO user (name, age, email, town) values("James Bond", 45, "bond@mi6.uk", "London")')
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO user (name, age, email, town) values("Rambo", 45, "rambo@usa.com", "Washington")')

    con.commit()

# --- main ---

con = sqlite3.connect("user_info.db")
cur = con.cursor()

create(con)

root = tk.Tk()

tv = ttk.Treeview(root)
tv.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
tv.config(columns= ("name", 'age', 'email', 'town'))

tv.heading('#0', text='ID')
tv.column('#0', width = 100)

tv.heading('1', text = "Age")
tv.column('1', width = 100)

tv.heading('name', text = 'Name')
tv.column('name', width = 100)

tv.heading('2', text = "email")
tv.column("2", width = 100)

tv.heading('3', text = "Town")
tv.column("3", width = 100)

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user')
for number, row in enumerate(cur.fetchall()):
    print(row)
    item = 'item{}'.format(number)
    tv.insert("", 'end', item, text=row[0])
    tv.set(item, 'name', row[1])
    tv.set(item, 'age', row[2])
    tv.set(item, 'email', row[3])
    tv.set(item, 'town', row[4])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i tried your code and got this "value for "-text" missing"

Comment: If you have already database then you have to skip `create()`. But you could move (or remove) database file to start with fresh database. It creates database and adds two rows so it has data to display it.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works really well and will help with my project. i just have to work out how you did it in case i need to a similar thing

Comment: first I found in Google SQL which creates table - I never remeber it. Next I created  `INSERT` to have some data to display. `fetchall()` always returns list with rows so I always use `for`-loop to get row and do something with this row. In other situation I would also use inner `for`-loop to get item from row, or I would use `len(row)` to check if there is enough items in row. Of course all time I used  `print()` to see check values in variables. Some modules have function to return rows as dictionary so I would use `row["name"]` (etc.) instead of `row[1]` - but I don't remeber function.

Comment: BTW: after `SELECT` you can see column's names in result using `print(cur.description)` or with this module `print([col[0] for col in cur.description])`

Comment: if you use `con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` before `cur = con.cursor()` then you can use `row['name']` and `row[1]` at the same time.